# MySQL determine whether to put single quotes around a string or not if MySQL function for custom class

Tags: php, mysql, regex, class

I am creating a custom class to make connecting to and using mysql easier in general. I have created many functions and all works fine except one part. I cannot seem to figure out how to determing if a string is an actual string or if it is a mysql function in order to put quotes around it or not. I put together a function that I can pass two parameters and it will insert into the database. The first parameter is the table to insert into, while the second parameter is an array of column, value pairs. Maybe this code example will help you understand a bit more. Note: I am escaping all strings already and have removed that code to show simplicity of problem.

```
function insert($table,array $array){
    $table = "`".$table."`";
    $columns = "";
    $values = "";
    foreach($array as $key => $value){
        $columns = ($columns=="") ? "`".$key."`" : $columns.", `".$key."`";
        if($value===NULL || $value=="NULL"){
            $value = "NULL";
        } else {
            $value = "'".$value."'";
        }
        $values = ($values=="") ? "".$value."" : $values.", ".$value."";
    }
    $query = "INSERT INTO $table ($columns) VALUES ($values)";
    return $this->query($query);
}
```

Here is an example of two different uses and the expected results or each

```
$data = array(
  "first_name"=>"John",
  "last_name"=>"Doe",
  "entry_date"=>"2013-08-26"
);
$MyClass->insert("people",$data);
```

would execute

```
INSERT INTO `people` (`first_name`,`last_name`,`entry_date`) VALUES ('John','Doe','2013-08-26')
```

which is expected However the following use:

```
$data = array(
  "first_name"=>"John",
  "last_name"=>"Doe",
  "entry_date"=>"NOW()"
);
$MyClass->insert("people",$data);
```

would execute as

```
INSERT INTO `people` (`first_name`,`last_name`,`entry_date`) VALUES ('John','Doe','NOW()')
```

which will not work because MySQL functions will not be operated if they are withing quotation marks. I know that this may be a small security risk because it would allow functions from the user if not caught. Is there a better way to do this or should MySQL functions not be allowed in an class insert function like this? If there is a regex that someone has put together to find and allow mysql functions then that might be a solution. If no such regex exists then one possibility would be to write one from scratch which I am not too good at...

**EDIT:**

Another solution which I will be using in the meantime is to get the date with PHP when forming the array. I would like to be using MySQL functions if possible still though. Here is my current code which solves the problem but not how I prefer:

```
$data = array(
  "first_name"=>"John",
  "last_name"=>"Doe",
  "entry_date"=>date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
);
$MyClass->insert("people",$data);
```

Comment: `if(preg_match("/^[A-Z_]+\(.*?\)/", $value)) { // Mysql function }`

Comment: @phpisuber01 perfect reg-ex, I [tested](http://regexpal.com/) it and it works perfectly. If you want to convert this to an answer then I will consider it for the best answer among any other answers that come in, but so far this appears to be working.

Answer (score 2):

I implemented a feature to do what you're describing for Zend Framework 1.0 a few years ago.

I solved it by distinguishing between a plain string scalar and an *object* that contains a string.

```
$data = array(
  "first_name"=>"John",
  "last_name"=>"Doe",
  "entry_date"=>new Zend_Db_Expr("NOW()")
);
$MyClass->insert("people",$data);
```

That way my framework can tell the difference between a PHP string that I intend to be treated
as an SQL string (i.e. quoted), versus a string that is rolled up in an object.

```
if($value===NULL || $value=="NULL"){
    $value = "NULL";
} else if ($value instanceof Zend_Db_Expr) {
    $value = $value->__toString(); // no quotes
} else {
    $value = "'".$value."'";
}
```

PS: Some people may advise you to use query parameters instead of concatenating escaped variables as you are doing.  I agree with that recommendation, but it really has little to do with your original question, so I won't go into it.  There are many other StackOverflow questions that deal with using query parameters.

---

Re your comment:

You could use regexes to match `NOW()` and every other MySQL function and treat them specially, but how can you insert the literal string "NOW()" (not the result of the function of that name)?

Answer: you can't -- just like you can't insert the literal string "NULL" in your current code, because you have treated that word as a special case.

You need some way to distinguish between the SQL expression `NOW()` and "NOW()".  Just because you don't need to insert that string into your database today doesn't mean you will never need that capability.  Remember you're designing this insert() function for general use against *any* table, current or future.

You are in fact designing a framework.

Comment: thanks for the recommendation and the answer. Writing more code into the array itself to form the object and then to test the object is not the route I want to go with this though. It needs to be a solution that can leave the array alone and just fix it within the class itself. And I am not using the Zend Framework. This might work for others, but not myself. sorry.

Comment: +1 for the point out that may be a requirement down the road but not for this application, but I will be reusing this custom framework for other applications so there is a need to consider these things.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @phpisuber1 for the regex `if(preg_match("/^[A-Z_]+\(.*?\)/", $value)) { // Mysql function }` and thanks @BillKarwin, with the two of you I have created a solution with a combination of your input.

The solution to me was add some more parameters to my classes function with default values to tell the function whether or not to insert as MySQL function or as string and also whether to insert as `NULL` or as string `"NULL"` see new function below:

```
/**
 * @param string $table the table to insert array into
 * @param array $array contains column => value pairs values may be MySQL Function
 * @param bool $mysql_functions true to insert mysql functions as function, false to insert mysql functions as string
 * @param bool $null_string_is_null true to insert string "NULL" as NULL; false to insert string "NULL" as string "NULL"
 * @param bool $empty_string_is_null true to insert string "" as NULL; false to insert string "" as string ""
 * @return bool Returns FALSE on failure. For successful queries will return TRUE.
 */
function insert($table,array $array,$mysql_functions = false,$null_string_is_null = true,$empty_string_is_null = false){
    $table = "`".$table."`";
    $columns = "";
    $values = "";
    foreach($array as $key => $value){
        $columns = ($columns=="") ? "`".$key."`" : $columns.", `".$key."`";
        if($value===NULL || ($value=="NULL" && $null_string_is_null) || ($value=="" && $empty_string_is_null)){
            $value = "NULL";
        } else if(preg_match("/^[A-Z_]+\(.*?\)/", $value) && $mysql_functions) {
            $value = "".$value."";
        } else {
            $value = "'".$value."'";
        }
        $values = ($values=="") ? "".$value."" : $values.", ".$value."";
    }
    $query = "INSERT INTO $table ($columns) VALUES ($values)";
    return $this->query($query);
}
```

This again is not the full function as I have left parts out for security reasons, but this is a functioning version. I will be looking into query parameters and see if it will increase security for this and other functions instead of concatenating escaped strings. The default parameters for this function work for my default use and can be changed for future uses. Overall I think this is the best solution. If you think otherwise I would love to read your comments.